# MySQL copy column value from several columns to one column

Tags: mysql, copy, mysql-workbench

I want to copy the latest information from table 1 into table 2.
For the ID i used

insert into Table2(ID) (Select ID FROM Table2). That was not a problem.
CL1 contains the oldest data.
CL3 contains the newest data. So CL2 is between.

Insert into was probably the easiest way to copy the ID from Table1 to Table2

my problem with MySQL is the following.

Table 1

```
    ID | CL1 | CL2 | CL3
    A  | 1   | 2   | 3
    B  | 1   | 2   | NULL
    C  | 1   | 2   | 3
    D  | 1   | NULL| NULL
    E  | 1   | 2   | 3


    Table 2
    ID | CLX
    A  |
    B  |
    C  |
    D  |
    E  |
```

---

Result should be:

```
    Table 2
    ID | CLX
    A  | 3
    B  | 2
    C  | 3
    D  | 1
    E  | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

use `GREATEST()`.

*Assuming that `CL1` is not nullable, and `CL3` cannot have value unless `CL2` is filled up.*

```
INSERT INTO table2(ID, CLX)
SELECT ID, GREATEST(CL1, COALESCE(CL2, CL1), COALESCE(CL3, CL1))
FROM table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d055/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

Coalesce was the function I need for my queries.

```
`Select ID, COALESCE(CL3,CL2,CL1) as latest from table1`
```